# why am i getting deprecation warning in notification..?

Tags: android, notifications

```
NotificationManager nm=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification n=new Notification(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_more , "My Alarm Ringing", System.currentTimeMillis());
Context cn=MainActivity.this;
CharSequence title="My Alarm Clock";
CharSequence details="Alarm Ringing....!!!";
Intent in=new Intent(cn,Alarm.class);
PendingIntent p=PendingIntent.getActivity(cn, 0, in, 0);
n.setLatestEventInfo(cn,title,details,p);
nm.notify(0,n);
```

In ecllipse i am getting Notification in second line and setLatestEventInfo in last second line is striked of. why is it so..?
can anyone clearify what is the mistake..?
thanx for the help

Comment: see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) `setLatestEventInfo method was deprecated in API level 11. Use Notification.Builder instead`

Comment: @Sud That constructor is deprecated, use ``Notification.Builder`` instead.

Comment: notfication.builder is for API level 11 and above bt m developing app on level 8 and above so it wont work in this case i guess

Comment: You could try setting minSdk to 8.  If that doesn't work, try setting targetSdk to 8.  If all else fails, Eclipse lets you fine-tune which warnings are flagged.

Answer (score 3):

[Deprecation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation) is

> a status applied to features, characteristics, or practices to indicate that they should be avoided, typically because they have been superseded.

The warning alerts you to a deprecated method in your target SDK so that you can try to avoid using it.

In this specific context, the warning suggests that you use [`Notification.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) instead, however if your needs do not allow you to use `Notification.Builder`, due to backwards compatability, or otherwise, you can (most likely) continue to use `setLatestEventInfo` without issue. It seems that this is just an upgrade to the API, not something particularly important that you need to avoid.

Comment: Use `Notification.Builder` instead.

Comment: @dicarlo2 .. Not a possibility if he is using **minSdk 8** .. He can set target sdk to 8 instead....

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a big fan of deprecation.  I still have a significant fraction of my customer base running 1.5 and 1.6, so there's no way I'm going to use any APIs newer than API 3 if I can avoid it.  Just because the old interface is deprecated doesn't mean I'm going to stop using it without a good reason.

Comment: @EdwardFalk Indeed, I updated my post with a note saying that it's not always important to switch to using a non-deprecated method, especially if you have a good reason not to. Considering that it seems like it's just an upgrade in the API, I wouldn't fret about not switching to `Notification.Builder`.

Comment: The good reason to avoid using deprecated methods and classes is that they usually gets deleted afterwards. For instance, setLatestEventInfo has been deleted in SDK version 23.

Answer (score 2):

Notification.setLatestEventInfo() was depreceated in API 11 ([source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#setLatestEventInfo%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)). As others have mentioned, you should be using Notification.Builder instead. ([source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html))

If you are using and API that is prior to API 11 you can use the compatibility package that Android has made available. Using this library will allow you to use API 11 and above for devices running API 11 and below. [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)

Also, just so you know, instead of using Notification.Builder() you need to use NotificationCompat.Builder().

Answer (score 2):

use NotificationCompat for older versions.

```
private NotificationCompat.Builder buildNormal() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext.getApplicationContext());

    b.setAutoCancel(true)
     .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
     .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())         
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
     .setTicker("Optional ticker")            
     .setContentTitle("Default notification")
     .setContentText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
     .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS| Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE| Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
     .setContentIntent(buildPendingIntent())
     .setContentInfo("Info");


    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Beacuse in the target SDK you have mentioned this method is deprecated...  simple.

Its better to read the documentation instead [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#setLatestEventInfo%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-notifications, "This release removes the Notification.setLatestEventInfo() method. Use the Notification.Builder class instead to construct notifications." Using API Level 23 for Android 6.0, my code does not even compile when I try to use setLatestEventInfo(). I get the following error:

```
Error:(86, 15) error: cannot find symbol method setLatestEventInfo(Context,String,String,PendingIntent)
```

You said you were using API Level 17. I can only confirm you cannot use setLatestEventInfo() if you are trying to compile your code with API Level 23.

Comment: I read at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474116/the-constructor-notification-is-deprecated that "the constructor for Notification is deprecated as of API 11". We should use this now: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html.