# The constructor notification is deprecated

Tags: android, push-notification

I am very new to android app development. With the help of so many tutorials, i created an app with webview, actionbar and GCM. Everything works fine. But i am getting a warning "The constructor notification is deprecated". I have gone through notification.builder. but i am not able to modify my codes with new notification buider. Can someone help me.....

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

public GCMIntentService() {
    super(SENDER_ID);
}

/**
 * Method called on device registered
 **/
@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
    displayMessage(context, "Your device registred with GCM");
    Log.d("NAME"," "+ MainActivity.name);
    ServerUtilities.register(context, MainActivity.name, MainActivity.email, MainActivity.AndroidVersion, MainActivity.AndroidID, MainActivity.manufacturer, MainActivity.model, registrationId);
}

/**
 * Method called on device un registred
 * */
@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
    displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
    ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
}

/**
 * Method called on Receiving a new message
 * */
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

    displayMessage(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message);
}

/**
 * Method called on receiving a deleted message
 * */
@Override
protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
    String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
    displayMessage(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message);
}

/**
 * Method called on Error
 * */
@Override
public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
    displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
}

@Override
protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
    // log message
    Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
    displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error,
            errorId));
    return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
}

/**
 * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
 */
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

}

}
```

****Manifest sdkversion 8 to 18

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You're attempting to use the constructor for Notification which is deprecated as of API 11.  Meaning it isn't supported any longer and should not be used.  use Notification.Builder instead https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html

```
 Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
     .setContentTitle("New mail from " + sender.toString())
     .setContentText(subject)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
     .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
     .setContentIntent(yourPendingIntent)
     .build();
```

You currently have the following :

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
```

This constructor is deprecated in favor of the Notification.Builder which would look like the following :

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
    .setContentText(message)
    .setSmallIcon(icon)
    .setWhen(when)
    .build();
```

Comment: No I couldnt figure out

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example that should work for your code

Comment: what if i need to support android 2.2.. which solution should i use?

Comment: Newton, you'll need to check the OS version and perform the appropriate calls accordingly.  Something like `if (currentapiVersion <= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO){
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
} else{
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
    .setContentText(message)
    .setSmallIcon(icon)
    .setWhen(when)
    .build();
}`

Comment: My problem with Android Studio is that GCMBaseIntentService itself in unresolvable. How to cope with that?

Comment: @Fabrizio, The GCMBaseIntentService is also deprecated in favor of the http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html

Comment: I already found that. The problem is that it is a totally different protocol and my own solution comes from a tutorial; I am myself a novice to Android coming from the iOS world. So I have no idea how to transform my code, possibly not broking the clients and php support. Do you know of any tutorial for using it? My old code is reported at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930533/replacing-gcmbaseintentservice-for-remote-notifications-while-switching-to-andro

Comment: In fact that page is totally inadequate if the reader does not already know the issue. Basically I would like to replace all the methods in my class and keep receving notifications even after adopting this new protocol, I frankly never wanted, especially as a 'present' during my switch from Eclipse to Andorid Studio....

Comment: At any rate I found http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/ that seems to solve the issue. I will test it tomorrow.

Comment: Not so fast, unfortunately, the project is done in Eclipse and will not import in Android Studio. I will try and inject the code into my project and hope for the best.

Answer (score 1):

As for the original question, this class works fine, if your system supports GCMBaseIntentService:

```
package ...;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

import static com.example.taxiprofessional.CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID;
import static com.example.taxiprofessional.CommonUtilities.displayMessage;

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

 public GCMIntentService() {
     super(SENDER_ID);
 }

 /**
  * Method called on device registered
  **/
 @Override
 protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
     Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
     displayMessage(context, "Your device registred with GCM");
     AccountInformation info=AccountInformation.sharedInstance();
     ServerUtilities.register(context, info.email, info.password, registrationId);
 }

 /**
  * Method called on device un registred
  * */
 @Override
 protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
     Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
     displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
     ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
 }

 /**
  * Method called on Receiving a new message
  * */
 @Override
 protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
     String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

     displayMessage(context, message);
     // notifies user
     generateNotification(context, message);
 }

 /**
  * Method called on receiving a deleted message
  * */
 @Override
 protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
     Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
     String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
     displayMessage(context, message);
     // notifies user
     generateNotification(context, message);
 }

 /**
  * Method called on Error
  * */
 @Override
 public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
     Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
     displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
 }

 @Override
 protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
     // log message
     Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
     displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error,
             errorId));
     return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
 }

 /**
  * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
  */
 private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
     int icon = R.drawable.taxi_profi;
     long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
     NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
             context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

     String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

     Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Dashboard.class);
     // set intent so it does not start a new activity
     notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
             Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
     PendingIntent intent =
             PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
     notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
     notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

     // Play default notification sound
     notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

     // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
     notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
     notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

 }

}
```